# Is there a way to execute a file/folder in a folder while I cd into it in the kernel. I am using Unix based systems (Arch, Manjaro, MacOSX, etc)

Tags: file, unix, kernel

Is there a way to execute a file while i'm in cd in the kernel. I am using Unix based systems (Arch, Manjaro, MacOSX, etc). I am trying to get htop for macOSX Big Sur, and I wrote `cd /Users/peter/Downloads/htop-master` . What should I do to execute the file (or is there even a way to execute it) now that i am into the file? Also, I am a beginner in the unix and linux space, so I'm not the brightest out there, so any advice helps. **Thank you**!

Comment: What does it mean "i'm in cd in the kernel"? What does it mean "i am into the file"? It seems that your question is not about *programming*, so it is **off-topic** here. See [help/on-topic].

Comment: The [README](https://github.com/htop-dev/htop) file tells you how to build the executable from source.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure the file is executable, you can run:

```sh
$ chmod +x $FILE
```

To make it executable, where `$FILE` in your case is `/Users/peter/Downloads/htop-master`, you might need `sudo` privileges to run the command. After that, you run htop:

```sh
$ /Users/peter/Downloads/htop-master
```

If your file is executable (ie a script or binary file) it should work. However, in your question you mentioned executing a directory, while all directories are executable, it doesn't mean you can run them as programs, it means you can `cd` into them.

If you downloaded the source code for `htop`, you'd first need to build it (compile it). That process varies from program to program, but generally, there is a `Makefile` that handles that for you. You'd need to check the process and requirements for htop, you should be able to find that from the website where you downloaded the program.

While I don't use MacOS, I believe there is a package manager called `brew` that can install `htop` for you. A package manager is a terminal program that installs programs from trusted sources automatically, it also handles dependencies and updates for you. I highly recommend you check it out.

Finally, I'd like to clarify some terms you seem to have confused:

- Kernel: The kernel is the core of the operating system, its job is to comunicate software and hardware, you don't normally interact with it, unless you are developing drivers or code that interacts in some lower level way with the hardware.
- Terminal: This is what you probably meant by kernel, it is commonly a Terminal Emulator, a program that lets you use a terminal from within a graphic environment. It is usually a black box with white text (or viceversa). The name comes from the days in which computers had to be shared, every user had a terminal, a dumb box that allowed the user to interact with the computer.
- Folder: While this term is completely correct, when using terminal programs, folders are more commonly referred to as Directories. Directory was the original term, but once graphical environments took off, the name Folder became more popular.

UNIX-like systems may seem complicated at first, but once you get the hang of it you'll realize they are way easier than Windows systems, welcome aboard!